# ¿Que función tienen los atributos android:targetPackage y android:targetClass a la hora de crear un Android Shortcut?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación Android y querría aplicar las nuevas funciones de los Android Shortcuts a mi aplicación.
Hasta ahora siguiendo los pasos que he encontrado ya tengo el shortcut, lo veo en el smartphone, pero al clicarle no hace nada, no tiene funcionalidad en sí, creo que esto se debe a mi desconocimiento de que hace cada cual atributo preguntado anteriormente.
Os dejo a continuación el xml del shortcut:

```
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.materialnotes.activity"
        android:targetClass="com.materialnotes.activity.EditNoteActivity"/>
    <categories android:name="android.shortcut.conversation" />
</shortcut>
```

Answer (score 1):

He logrado arreglarlo, efectivamente tenía mal puesto uno de los atributos mencionados, el `android:targetPackage`, se soluciona con la siguiente linea `android:targetPackage="com.materialnotes"`
Estaba referenciando mal el Package, pues estaba referenciando una carpeta dentro del package.